# Accidentally deleted cfg80211 Ubuntu 22.04 Kernel version 5.15.0-43-generic

Tags: networking, apt, kernel, 22.04

While trying to install some adapter drivers as shown [here](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu), I accidentally deleted my `/lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/net/wireless/` directory completely where `cfg80211.ko` is stored, and I would like to repair it if possible.

I've tried running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic` and similar combinations but that simply gives me `Reinstallation of linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic is not possible, since it cannot be downloaded.`

Thank you

Comment: "since it cannot be downloaded" Because, without wireless, you have no internet connection available? Can you tether your phone? I believe the package you want to reinstall is linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r).

Comment: @chili555 As of now I'm accessing the internet by USB tethering through my phone and there's something wrong with my wireless card. The end goal is to install drivers for a USB adapter I bought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sadly can't easily reinstall old kernel versions. Is there anything that's holding you on 5.15.0-43?

If not, just run `sudo apt install linux-generic` which should give you the most current one (5.15.0-83 on my machine) and reboot.